# Expand Textarea Horizontally

Tags: jquery, plugins, textarea, autogrow

I found this JQuery plugin: https://github.com/rotundasoftware/jquery.autogrow-textarea

I follow the related guide, but I didn't get any result.
I tried to call this in my `document.ready()`

```
$( "textarea" ).autogrow( { vertical : true, horizontal : true } );
```

Can anybody show me how use it correctly?

Comment: you need to check whether your form loads completely with this textarea first

Comment: Ok this could be the reason

Comment: your external resource is not being able to execute in FIDDLE .you can check error s in console .

Comment: try this http://plugins.jquery.com/autogrow/ plugin

Comment: Solved, this post can be deleted. Tushar issue was correct

Comment: autogrow doesn't work horizontally

Comment: okay . you can write that in your answer so that others knows too the solution if you want .

Answer (score 0):

The error was in the loading, first must load textarea, then autorow it